# akka cluster : configuration seed node

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I have a sample question

Does it make sense to configure all the nodes of the akka cluster as seed nodes?

example:

```
cluster {
  seed-nodes = [
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2551",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2552",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2553",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2554",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2555",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2556",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2557",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2558",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2559",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2560",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2561",
   "akka://application@127.0.0.1:2562"]

  downing-provider-class = "akka.cluster.sbr.SplitBrainResolverProvider"
     
  split-brain-resolver {
    active-strategy = static-quorum
       
    static-quorum {
      quorum-size = 7 
    }
  }
```

Are there disadvantages for this configuration?

Comment: I would say no disadvantages since the documentation says `After the joining process the seed nodes are not special and they participate in the cluster in exactly the same way as other nodes.` https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer has to be "it depends".

Seed nodes is **one** mechanism that enables new nodes to join akka cluster.
For your example to work you have to run all the nodes on the same host. I am guessing you're passing some JVM argument like `-Dakka.remote.artery.canonical.port=2***` to bind each node to different port. That's fine, it will work. A new node starting up will try to join the cluster by contacting the seed nodes starting from the first until one of them responds.

In practice you probably want the cluster nodes running on different machines and that's when a static configuration like the one in your example can become a bit of a pain. This is because you'd need to know all the IP addresses beforehand and would need to guarantee that they will not change over time. This is perhaps possible in a network with statically assigned IPs but is nearly impossible with dynamically assigned IPs or in environments like Kubernetes. This is why there are other methods of cluster joining implemented (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/discovery/index.html).

So the disadvantage I see here is limitation of this configuration in any real-life scenario. As long as you're doing this to learn/experiment with Akka cluster, then it's all fine, though you can also argue that if you're doing that, then having a list of 12 seed nodes does not give you that much advantage over say 2 seed nodes as long as you can keep them up and running for the time of your experiment so that all the nodes can join the cluster.